# How do we install Unity-2D and dependencies offline?

Tags: 11.04, installation, unity-2d, offline

We have installed 11.04 32-bit on an old machine that has no internet connection and with a graphics card that is not suitable for running Compiz or Unity. Still, we would like to run Unity-2D on this machine.

We are aware of answers to [this Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-offline). Sadly Keryx will not run on 11.04 32-bit because of unmet dependencies. Building an offline repository is not an option because of limited storage capacity.

Is there any convenient other way to find, download, install, and eventually update unity-2 and all dependencies (preferably from an OS independent download path)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I am using 11.04 and keryx after you pointed me to the link. Thanks by the way. Did a bit googling and found [keryx ppa](https://launchpad.net/~keryx-admins/+archive/keryx-ppa) which is for lucid. Basically installed debian package presented [there](https://launchpad.net/~keryx-admins/+archive/keryx-ppa/+files/keryx_0.92.5-0ubuntu1_all.deb). It's running on 11.04 so may be you could try that.

Comment: Thank you for the link to the deb. Still, this will not allow installation of Keryx on this vanilla 11.04 because of unmet dependencies from python.

Comment: I'd say install the dependencies by hand, http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.1/ if you need python 2.7

Comment: Keryx depends on python **<<** 2.7 and will not run with python 2.7 when forced to install. That is a problem in 11.04. There are other unmet dependencies too.

Comment: you can try installing `python2.6-minimal` package and see. I have installed keryx from deb and viewed its dependencies on the python part it doesnot say which version while it depends on wxpython and python-support as well

Comment: then install an older version http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.6.6/

Comment: Keryx runs fine on my 64-bit 11.04 box at home but no luck so far on this 32-bit offline PC - I now have a lot of offline packages I would need to install in the right order. Not so much of a good idea so far.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure ,because it's repository from indonesia, [Apt-web](http://apt-web.dahsy.at) type what you want and it comes up with all dependencies

Comment: works like a charm - very nice!

Comment: proud to be indonesian