# How to install firefox-5 without a PPA?

Tags: 10.04, firefox

I want to install firefox 5 on my work Lucid machine. However, I can't access external repositories from my machine, so PPAs are ruled out. What alternative methods are available to install firefox 5?

Comment: See [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/40272) and [another question](http://askubuntu.com/q/974) for solutions.

Answer (score 1):

here you go  *http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/all-beta.html*

Comment: Isn't that just the generic linux source? I was hoping for set of debians that set up the menu and stuff too.

Comment: No, that's a compressed tarball containing the binaries. Those are built for 32-bit machines and you might have a few issues with using those on a 64-bit system.

Comment: Don't know why you'd want Firefox 5beta7, when the final is out. Here are the links to 32 and 64 bit Firefox 5.0: ftp://releases.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/5.0/                                           Creating a menu launcher is also really easy, just edit the menu and add a new launcher.

Answer (score 0):

it's been released in the normal repos for 11.04

for older versions, here's the [latest download page](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/all.html)

all you have to do is extract the files to a directory of your choice and update your default application settings to run the firefox file in that directory

Comment: He is talking about Lucid, there is no packages in Lucid's repos for firefox 5.

Comment: whoops, well spotted